# Using Ajax to POST to PHP Shopify API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi I am trying to create a button that will call a PHP function to add products to Shopify from web application.

**File 1**: http://codepad.org/MPs4y1Qu which has my Amazon Code and calling Amazon Products.
This File has code which is calling that button on the rightside `add` which will import those products to my Shopify store.

**P.S** I have tested my shopify API separately and it is working 100%

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){

 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'create_product.php',
 success: function(data) {
 prompt(data);


 }
 });
 });
});
</script>
```

File 2: create_product.php http://codepad.org/at7LtcMK which has my Shopify API 
it has Arrays like Title, body_html which has static value but will replace it Amazon Title  and so on..

Now the problem is upon testing when I click on button add nothing happens. even my ajax has 200 OK message but I need code to make it successful. I have tried above but not working.